# Extracting a value, applying logic and printing the new value?

Tags: java, string, methods, gettext, settext

I have been scratching my head for a week trying to work out why my program isn't working as expected. I could give up and try something different, but I feel that I wouldn't be learning if I were to do that. Not only this, I feel to invested as I have spent ages getting to where I am now.

If someone could give me a nudge in the right direction, the help would be geatly appreciated.

The problem I have is that I cant extract the values of all the fields and then make a calculation (conversion issues, from int to string). I can do each extraction seperatly, but using each of the extracted values together doesn't seem to work?

The source code I have is too long to be entered onto the site with my question, so I have tried to describe an example of my problem here. I hope I have made this understandable. Thanks in advance.

```
xCocaine -------- JLabel
tCocaine -------- JTextField
bCocaine--------- JButton

pCocaineValue --- JLabel
pCashValue------- JLabel
```

xCocaine is a JLabel that represents the current and randomly generated price of cocaine. tCocaine is an input field that allows a user to enter the quantity of cocaine they wish to buy at the price represented on the JLabel xCocaine.

bCocaine is the button that allows a user to buy cocaine, calculating the price and quantity of cocaine wanted. The purchase will be conditional, based on whether the user has enough money.

If the user has enough money which is represented by the JLabel pCashValue, the conditions for sale will be met and the purchase is confirmed by subtracting the value of the sale from pCashValue and updating pCocaineValue, which is the JLabel indicating the quantity of cocaine purchased by the user.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the String value of your Jlabel by using the method String result = xCocaine.getText().
Then Convert it to a double to make calculation: double price = Double.parseDouble(result);

It is the same process for a JTextField.

Then write the calculation in the ActionListener of your JButton.

Answer (score 0):

**For converting String to int**

```
Integer.parseInt(yourString);
```

**For int to String:**

```
String.valueOf(yourInt)
```

**For getting value from JTextField:**

```
String value = editText.getText().toString();
```

**For setting on JLable:**

```
lable.setText(value);
```

Comment: Thanks folks, brilliant work. All is working well.